# calculate a derived column in sql

Tags: sql, derived-column

I have a following query which produces table below:-

```
select * from temp_3

bucket  values
OTIF+2  319
OTIF    24987              
null    1347               
OTIF+>2 515
OTIF+1  552
```

Now I need the values to be in percentage of the total sum of values for which I wrote following query :-

```
select sum(values) as total into temp_1 from temp_3
select bucket, (values/(select total from temp_1)) as score from temp_3
```

But that led to following result :-

```
bucket  values
OTIF+2  0
OTIF    0              
null    0               
OTIF+>2 0
OTIF+1  0
```

can anyone give me an idea as to how we can convert that efficiently into percentage form ? and where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Integer arithmetic, 5/20 produces 0. Convert it to decimal for example `values * 1.0/(select total from temp_1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select bucket, value,
       value * 1.0 / sum(value) over ()
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(values) as total into temp_1 from temp_3
select bucket, (values * 100) /total as score from temp_3, temp_1
```

or just

```
select bucket, (values * 100) /sum(values) as score from temp_3
```